# Appending CSV files, matching unordered columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Problem: matching columns while appending CSV files

I have 50 .csv files where each column is a word, each row is a time of day and each file holds all words for one day. They look like this:

```
Date  Time Aword Bword Cword Dword
Date1 t1   0     1     0     12
Date1 t2   0     6     3     0

Date  Time Eword Fword Gword Hword Bword
Date2 t1   0     0     1     0     3
Date2 t2   2     0     0     19    0
```

I want to append the files so that any columns with the same word (like Bword in this example) are matched while new words are added in new columns:

```
Date  Time Aword Bword Cword Dword Eword Fword Gword Hword
Date1 t1   0     1     0     12                       
Date1 t2   0     6     3     0                        
Date2 t1         3                 0     0     1     0   
Date2 t2         0                 2     0     0     19
```

I'm opening the csv files as dataframes to manipulate them and using dataframe.append the new files are added like this:

```
Date  Time Aword Bword Cword Dword
Date1 t1   0     1     0     12
Date1 t2   0     6     3     0
Date  Time Eword Fword Gword Hword Bword
Date2 t1   0     0     1     0     3
Dat2e t2   2     0     0     19    0
```

Is there a different approach which could align matching columns while appending? ie without iterating through each column and checking for matches.

*Sincere apologies if this question is too vague, I'm new to python and still struggling to know when I'm thinking un-pythonically and when I'm using the wrong tools.*

EDIT: more information
1) I'll need to perform this task multiple times, once for each of five batches of csvs
2) The files all have 25 rows but have anything from 5 to 294 columns
3) The order of rows is important Day1(t1, t2...tn) then Day2(t1, t2...tn)
4) The order of columns is not important

Comment: There are various solutions to this, and which is best depends on a couple of things. (1.) Is this a one-off task or something that's going to be running repeatedly (and if the latter, in what context?) (2.) How large are the files?

Comment: 1) I'll need to perform this task multiple times, once for each of five batches of csvs.
2) The files all have 25 rows but have anything from 5 to 294 columns.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can simply use `pd.concat`, which will automatically align on columns:

```
>>> csvs = glob.glob("*.csv")
>>> dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv) for csv in csvs]
>>> df_merged = pd.concat(dfs).fillna("")
>>> df_merged
  Aword  Bword Cword   Date Dword Eword Fword Gword Hword Time
0     0      1     0  Date1    12                           t1
1     0      6     3  Date1     0                           t2
0            3        Date2           0     0     1     0   t1
1            0        Date2           2     0     0    19   t2
```

(Although I'd recommend either `fillna(0)` or leaving it as `nan`; if you fill with an empty string to look like your desired output, the column has to have object dtype and those are much slower than int or float.)

If you're really particular about the column order, you could cheat and use `(re)set_index`:

```
>>> df_merged.set_index(["Date", "Time"]).reset_index()
    Date Time Aword  Bword Cword Dword Eword Fword Gword Hword
0  Date1   t1     0      1     0    12                        
1  Date1   t2     0      6     3     0                        
2  Date2   t1            3                 0     0     1     0
3  Date2   t2            0                 2     0     0    19
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. When I use your approach I find the columns concat by index number rather than by column name (eg by 0, 1, 2, 3 instead of Aword, Bword etc). Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I think for this kind of thing you might find using the pandas library a bit easier. Say `filelist` is a list of file names.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fl, index_col=[0,1]) for fl in filelist])
```

And you're done! As a side note if you'd like to combine the date and time columns (depending on their format) you can try

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fl, parse_dates=['Date','Time']) for fl in filelist]).drop('Date', axis=1)
```

Comment: Oh, good idea to use `index_col`, although I think `index_col=[0,1]` would work even better.

Comment: Yes good point, I forgot also that you can combine the date and time columns if needed

Answer (score 0):

If the order of rows and columns is not important (if it is, you need to edit your Q to specify how to deal with it when the order differs among files!), there are no conflicts (different values of the same column for the same date and time), and the data fit in memory -- and you prefer to work in Python than in Pandas (I notice you haven't tagged your Q with `pandas`) -- one approach might be the following:

```
import collections
import csv

def merge_csvs(*filenames):
    result_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    all_columns = set()
    for fn in filenames:
        with open(fn) as f:
            dr = csv.DictReader(f)
            update_cols = True
            for row in dr:
                date = row.pop('Date')
                time = row.pop('Time')
                result_dict[date, time].update(row)
                if update_cols:
                    all_columns.update(row)
                    update_cols = False
    for d in result_dict:
        missing_cols = all_columns.difference(d)
        d.update(dict.from_keys(missing_cols, '')
    return result_dict
```

This produced a dictionary, keyed by `(date, time)` pairs, of dictionaries whose keys are all the columns found in any of the input CSVs, with either the corresponding value for that date and time, or else an empty string if that column was never found for that date and time.

Now you can deal with this as you wish, e.g

```
d = merge_csvs('a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv')
for date, time in sorted(d):
    dd = d[date, time]
    outlist = [dd[c] for c in sorted(dd)]
    print(date, time, outlist)
```

or, of course, write it back to a different CSV, and so forth.

Comment: Thank you, I'll clarify more:
1) The order of rows is important Day1(t1, t2...tn) then Day2(t1, t2...tn)
2) The order of columns is not important
3) I will tag the question with pandas now, that was my mistake
Then I will run your answer to make sure I understand how it works.
Thank you.

Comment: If the `(date, time)` pairs are to be ordered in ascending sequence, that's exactly what the `for date, time in sorted(d):` will do in the snippet at the end of my answer.  If in some other way, then said order need either to be imposed by a `key=` arg to `sorted`, or e.g separately recorded in a `list` as the `CSV`s are read, if for example the idea is to maintain whatever arbitrary order is in the `CSV`s in the first place.  Please edit Q further to specify exactly what the row order must be!